# Is there an alternative to Ansible on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, orchestration

I changed the Python 2 to Python 3. I felt the benefits of Asyncio.

Earlier in my project I used Ansible, but it is not supported with Python 3. Can you recommend to me an alternative to Ansible for Python 3?

Comment: You can install Python 2 and 3 in parallel and keep running Ansible on Python 2...!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2.2, Ansible works with Python 3. Yep, you may encounter some bugs but any patch related to py3 will be quickly reviewed and merged by the team. I already fixed two that I encountered myself.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: as of Ansible 2.2 this answer is no longer accurate.

> The best answer here is to have both versions of Python installed,
>   possibly running Python 2 and Ansible in a virtualenv.
>
> It's possible that Ansible will be refactored for Python 3 but it's
>   unlikely for now, and there is no Alternative in Python 3. If you
>   don't want to use Ansible on Python2, you'll need to switch to another
>   tool like Saltstack, Chef, or Puppet.